# Choosing noSQL - availability priorited

Tags: nosql, high-availability, failover

We have thought a bit about running a noSQL database for our next project. However, we're not sure about which platform that will give us the best possible availability and has the best built-in replication features/functions to provide this - with the least headache.

Right now, Cassandra appears as the best candidate, but we would like to hear more about this from someone that have more experience in this area, then we do.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

High availablity will most likely be achieved with a Dynamo clone.
Cassandra is a good option although it has been [bashed](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/7/11/so-why-is-twitter-really-not-using-cassandra-to-store-tweets.html) recently by [several](http://blog.reddit.com/2010/05/reddits-may-2010-state-of-servers.html) early adapters.
[Project Voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/) is also Dynamo-based and therefore easily optimized for high-availability, it's what LinkedIn are using.
Another interesting noSQL option might be [membase](http://membase.org/), I myself didn't use it but their notion of virtual buckets for rebalancing as opposed to just consistent hashing makes a lot of sense and would appear to provide more robust high-availability.